# get reference to a node of std::map using key

Tags: c++

How to get reference to a node of `std::map` using key `std::pair<key_type, value_type>& node = map_obj[key];`. I know `operator[]` of `std::map` returns reference to value part, but I want reference to entire node (`std::pair<key_type, value_type>&`).

Comment: `std::map::find` returns an iterator

Comment: Please note: the `operator[]` returns always an existing entry. If it hasn't been there before, it's created. (This can be intended or not.) Thus, it's not sufficient to probe a map for the existence of an entry. Consequently, the `std::map::find()` returns an iterator which can (should) be compared to `std::map::end()` to check whether the searched entry doesn't exist.

Comment: Note the from an iterator we can only get a `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>&` (notice the `const`). Changing the key is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. Of course, this snippet assumes that the key exists in the map (*i.e.* `mymap.find("b") != mymap.end()`). Also, the first member of the pair has to be constant (as changing its values would invalidate the map).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> mymap = {{"a",5}, {"b", 7}};

    std::pair<const std::string, int> &mypair = *mymap.find("b");
    std::cout << mypair.first<< " " << mypair.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```